# How exactly can this martingale be bounded?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

We define $X_t:=e^{(\lambda-\kappa)t}(\frac{\kappa}{\lambda})^{N_t}$, where $N_t$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$ and both parameters $\lambda,\kappa>0$. I want to find an upper bound of

$$E[\sup_{0\le t\le T}X_t]$$

I thought the following:

- if $\lambda\ge \kappa$ then we have $E[\sup_{0\le t\le T}X_t]\le e^{(\lambda-\kappa)T}E[\sup_{0\le t\le T}\big(\frac{\kappa}{\lambda}\big)^{N_t}]\le e^{(\lambda-\kappa)T}$
- if $\lambda < \kappa$ then we have $E[\sup_{0\le t\le T}X_t]\le
     E[\sup_{0\le t\le
     T}\big(\frac{\kappa}{\lambda}\big)^{N_t}]\le E[\big(\frac{\kappa}{\lambda}\big)^{N_T}]$

I know that $N_T$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda T$. But how can I get a bound? Thanks for the help

hulik

Comment: Can't you just calculate the expectation $E\left[\left(\frac{\kappa}{\lambda}\right)^{N_T}\right]$?

Comment: Can't you just use Doob's inequality for martingales?

Comment: @Ilya This is from an exercise sheet and a priori you should not know that $S_t$ is a martingale. You just know that it is a local martingale. Showing that the $\sup$ is integrable you can conclude that it is a true martingale. And this is the aim of this exercise. I just calculated "for fun" $E[S_t|\mathcal{F_s}]$ and recognized already that $S$ has to be a martingale. However I want to do the exercise, as they suggest, therefore I can not use Doob. I edited my question.

Comment: Well, can't you then just use the fact that the latter expectation $E(\kappa/\lambda)^{N_T}$ is bounded for any $T$?

Comment: It seems like you're already done. The expectation I mentioned is actually given by $e^{T(\kappa-\lambda)}$ which is finite.

Comment: @Ilya That is what I want to show. I just realized, that this expectation is easy to calculate. $E[(\frac{\kappa}{\lambda})^{N_T}]=e^{T(\kappa-\lambda)}$ hence everything is fine. But is it that obvious, without calculating the expectation, that it is bounded?

Comment: @StefanHansen See my comment above, I just realized that this expectation is really easy to compute. But it is not that obvious a priori that it is bounde, isn't it?

Comment: I guess that depends on what obvious means. I couldn't come up with a bound just by looking at it, so I guess it wasn't obvious in that sense. But it is almost obvious, because calculating the expectation requires very little effort.

Comment: Well, this is just a moment generating function of $\mathrm{Poi}(\cdot)$. Perhaps, its finetness is not 100% obvious, but as Stefan mentioned it is *almost* obvious. Nevertheless, by no mean it is said to discourage you - if you have *any* doubts there are no words *too careful*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize what have been given in comments.

1. You can compute the expectation explicitly since this just involves some exponential series that are easy to deal with.
2. Note that for $x>0$ it holds that $\mathsf E[x^{N_T}] = \mathsf E[\exp(\xi\cdot\ln x)] = \mathrm {MGF}_\xi(\ln x)$ where $\xi\sim \mathrm{Poi}(\lambda T)$ and its MGF is hence finite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially for the second point

Comment: @hulik: welcome!